# touchstart blocking button listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, seadragon

I'm using Seadragon Ajax with jQuery touch event listeners.

The container has touchstart, touchmove and touchend bound to it, heres the touch start:

```
.bind('touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){

            var p = coord(e.originalEvent);
            p.start = true;
            p.scale = 1;
            if(e.originalEvent.pointerType === 4) return;
            else if(e.originalEvent.pointerType !== undefined) e.originalEvent.preventMouseEvent();

            $(this).data(p);            

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
```

Inside the seadragon view are some buttons generated. These buttons are not firing on a tablet because of the touchstart on its container div. It works fine with a mouse.

```
new Seadragon.Button("Click to go", "", "", "", "", null, moveFunction, null, null, null );
```

I need to check to see if the touch is on a button or not before all the stuff in the touchstart function but really am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding an if statement to check the number of touches as below:

```
.bind('touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
            if (event.touches.length != 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            var p = coord(e.originalEvent);
            p.start = true;
            p.scale = 1;
            if(e.originalEvent.pointerType === 4) return;
            else if(e.originalEvent.pointerType !== undefined) e.originalEvent.preventMouseEvent();

            $(this).data(p);        


        })
```